# Python .csv into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert the following csv

```
E1;4;6;7;1;3;6
E2;5;4;3;5;0;0
E3;2;3;3;0;0;0
```

into a Python dictionary withe the following structure:

```
d = {"E1": np.array([4,6,7,1,3,6])}
d["E2"] = np.array([5,4,3,5,0,0])
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show what you have tried based on your research into this task

Comment: How big is this file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: The file has about 50 rows and 10 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas`

```
>>> d = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', header=None).set_index(0).agg(np.array,1).to_dict()

{'E1': array([4, 6, 7, 1, 3, 6]),
 'E2': array([5, 4, 3, 5, 0, 0]),
 'E3': array([2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0])}
```

Using pure python:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip().split(';')
        d[l[0]] = np.array(list(map(int, l[1:])))

{'E1': array([4, 6, 7, 1, 3, 6]),
 'E2': array([5, 4, 3, 5, 0, 0]),
 'E3': array([2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read into a Pandas dataframe, transpose and then use a dictionary comprehension:

```
from io import StringIO

x = StringIO("""E1;4;6;7;1;3;6
E2;5;4;3;5;0;0
E3;2;3;3;0;0;0""")

# replace x with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(x, sep=';', header=None).set_index(0).T

d = {col: df[col].values for col in df}
```

Result:

```
{'E1': array([4, 6, 7, 1, 3, 6], dtype=int64),
 'E2': array([5, 4, 3, 5, 0, 0], dtype=int64),
 'E3': array([2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)}
```

If `list` values are sufficient, you can use `to_dict`:

```
d = pd.read_csv(x, sep=';', header=None).set_index(0).T.to_dict('list')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('input_file')
column_names = df.columns.tolist()
dict = {}
for col in column_names:
    dict[column_names[col]] = column_names.col.values
```

## Hope this helps!